# How to sum number with Number in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, numbers

It might seem as a trivial question, but I was not able to get any relevant results since google search is case insensitive.

Let's say I have following code:

```
items[5] = "5\,5"
totalAmount: number = 5
totalAmount = totalAmount + Number(items[5].replace( "\\,", "."));
```

and my IDE tells me that I cannot appy operands to type number and Number. 
When I serached for a method to turn string into a number, I was only met with the above solution, which is useless for me. How can I make a number typed variable from a string?

Comment: You can convert string to floting point number using `Number.parseFloat(your_num_str)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see any issue with your code and it work fine for me in Visual Studio Code but try following code and see if it works for you:

```
totalAmount: number = 5
totalAmount = totalAmount + parseFloat(items[5].replace( "\\,", "."));
```

Comment: found the issue. It was declared as totalAmount: Number = 5 i am so sorry...